# How to instantiate second managed bean on an xpage

Tags: xpages

I have an xpage where I want to have the user enter four input fields and then create a new document, and immediately have the document show in a dojo data grid on the same page.  I am using managed beans for all backend data.  I have one bean for the main document, and a second bean for each related data.  I will tie them together using the UNID.  The input fields are all bound to the shipperBean.

My issue is that the parent and only the ***first*** sub document is created.  It seems like I need to instantiate a new bean, but I thought that was done for you, as in 'managed' for you.

In my button I have the following SSJS:

```
var POdata:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(database.getServer(), "PO\\PO-data");
lineItemBean.saveLineItem(POdata);  //MUST save line item in order to tie Shipper to Line Item
var liUNID = lineItemBean.getThisUNID();
var poUNID = lineItemBean.getParentUNID();
shipperBean.saveShipper(POdata, liUNID, poUNID);
shipperBean.deleteCurrentShipper();
```

The button performs a partial refresh on the table holding the input.
The saveShipper() method saves the bean to a new document in a different nsf. 
The deleteCurrentShipper() method simply sets the instance vars to null.  This causes them to be wiped out and ready for the next document.  The front end correctly is updated to reflect the wiping out of the values.  Any entering of values after the first time not saved to a new document, although they are cleared each time on the front end.

Do I need to create a new instance each time, or can I reuse the same instance like I am attempting?

Should I use a POJO instead and create it myself?

Should I not use SSJS and do it all in another java method and call that?

Should I make the second bean a property of the first?

Is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using a managed bean as it does not seem to add much value to your process. In fact trying to reset the bean and its contents can cause issues to occur. Instead, define a series of java classes and use an Object Data source that is scoped to the anticipated lifecycle (usually view or request). The create method will then establish a new instance of the parent class each time a new "object' is being created. Try and have as little business logic encoded in the SSJS. The purpose of the SSJS should be to bind the front end (XSP code) to the back end (java classes). i.e. when I click on button A it should trigger a single method call applicable to the parent class. Create additional (child) classes to encapsulate different objects. As Knut has suggested us a collection of classes if you have a many-to-one relationship. The save method of your parent class can then trigger saves of the child classes back into Notes documents.

Comment: "as it does not seem to add much value to your process" - you can manage it by yourself, sure, but I think managed life cycle is worth using beans, in most of cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  It will take me a bit to process all this, but I will definitely update this and let you know the approach that worked best for my project.

Comment: I got it to work by changing to a POJO or Plain Old Java Object, and using the constructor to created the object myself.  I didn't have to change the class much from its former life as a bean.  Now I have better control.   Thanks for all the answers, but I am going to go with Peter's answer because it is very true that "using a managed bean does not seem to add much value".  I would say it is a square peg in round hole in this case.  Thanks again Peter, Frantisek, and Knut!

Answer (score 1):

If you define a "managed" bean in faces-config.xml then it means it gets instantiated on first usage automatically. But, it will exist only **one** instance within scope you defined (e.g. session). Every usage of the managed bean refers then to this one instance.

In your example it means that `lineItemBean` is created only at first time pressing button and then same instance is used for every next button click.

I think in your case it is better to go this way:

- create a `List<lineItemBean>` within your `shipperBean`
- add a new `lineItemBean` to the list in method `saveShipper()` and create documents in database there
- add a method `getAllLineItems()` which returns `List<lineItemBean>` for providing data to your data grid

Comment: Thanks Knut, I think that makes sense.  I will try it on Thurs when I am back in the office.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use this approach: http://www.mindoo.de/web/blog.nsf/dx/16.07.2009095816KLEBCY.htm

Your bean should implement Map interface and in get() method provide child objects according to key parameter. This way you can have very simple and "nice" bindings.

Let's say you have "table" bean providing objects "line" (child objects are not defined as beans in `faces-conig.xml`!). In table's get() method you will instantiate and cache, or retrieve from cache, proper line object. EL for some cell is "#{table[row_key].attribute}".